# Expresión regular sin espacio en blanco, guión (-) o punto (.)

Tags: java

En Java, tengo que encontrar una expresión que no contenga ningún espacio en blanco, guión (-) o punto (.).

He probado con lo siguiente:

```
String regex= "[\s]|[.]|[-]";

if (string.matches(regex){
System.out.print("La frase no es correcta");
}
```

Cuando recibe una frase con espacios da error.

Comment: Buen día, noté que tu publicación lleva algunos votos en contra, para ayudarte a mejorar la pregunta y que sea mejor recibida, por favor agrega la descripción de lo que está fallando y un ejemplo del resultado deseado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String regex= "[^\s.-]+";

String match = "fgo";
String nonmatch = "-";
        
        
if (nonmatch.matches(regex)){
     System.out.println("todo ok");
}else{
     System.out.println("tiene caracteres incorrectos");
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde esto a la pregunta? Lee [answer], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.